# AWS CLI - how to get when the file was changed

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

A client is uploading data we use to AWS S3. I need to find out when the uploads took place in the last week (or month). How could I go about that? If I use `aws s3 ls path` I get only the date of the *last* change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain historical information about Amazon S3 API calls, you can use **AWS CloudTrail**.

From [Logging Amazon S3 API Calls by Using AWS CloudTrail - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html):

> Amazon S3 is integrated with AWS CloudTrail, a service that provides a record of actions taken by a user, role, or an AWS service in Amazon S3. CloudTrail captures a subset of API calls for Amazon S3 as events, including calls from the Amazon S3 console and from code calls to the Amazon S3 APIs.

To use object-level logging, see: [How Do I Enable Object-Level Logging for an S3 Bucket with AWS CloudTrail Data Events? - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-cloudtrail-events.html)